# Rails Bootstrap 2.3.1 Navbar Color

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm already trying for hours but I can't figure out how to change the navbar color and the navbar text color in my rails bootstrap project. I've read about .navbar-inner in some css files but nothing I write in any file seems to have any effect. Maybe it's because of a newer version of bootstrap? Could someone please give me a step by step solution?

I've tried to change the "bootstrap_and_override.css / .css.less" files but nothing happened. Do I have to compile the .css.less file or something like that? Thank you very much!

Here is my gemfile if its relevant:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'


gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
#gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails" #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"

gem 'json'

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
    gem 'uglifier'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'therubyracer'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: Did you set the values before including the twitter bootstrap file?

Comment: No I didn't. This comment has to be at least 15 characters in length...

Comment: Have you tried overwriting the default .navbar-inner and .navbar .nav > li > a in your CSS to change the color of navbar and its text?

Comment: No I only tried to change the .navbar-inner. I looked at the css of the bootstrap in chrome and changed the colors there. It turned out that there is a gradient for .navbar-inner which is the correct one, but when I try to change it in my css file nothing changed. Do I have to change all of them you listed above?

Comment: But the CSS entries will be rendered?

Comment: Yes, the css I entered in the css-override file is shown in chrome but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the elements, like it's priority is too low or it gets overwritten. Should I prefer to use the less or normal css file to overwrite the standard bootstrap css?

Comment: Update: Ok, I don't know why but but suddenly the changes seem to be shown. (Only after upload to heroku, not local.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to customize the variable as instructed here:
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html#variables

Specifically, put this in the stylesheets section of your assets folder under whatever file you're using as the yourstylefile.css.sass.

```
$navbarBackgroundHighlight: coloryouwant; /* This changes the nag background color */
$navbarText: coloryouwant; /* This changes the text color */
```

*Make sure that this code appears ABOVE your @imports of bootstrap. Better to just stick it at the very top of the yourstylefile.css.sass just to be safe.